# Basic python usage, calling a function

Tags: python

I am working on leetcode but actually never wrote a file locally before.

```
class Solution(object):
    def singleNumber(self, nums):

        for i in range(0,len(nums),2):
            if (i != len(nums) - 1) and (nums[i] != nums[i+1]):
                print (nums[i])
            elif i == len(nums) - 1:
                print (nums[i])

    def main():
        nums=[1,1,2,2,3]
        s=Solution()
        s.singleNumber(nums)
        print('done')
```

I am running this script but not seeing any output and don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: With local python programs, the main code is always executed *outside* of a class. So you need to move your code inside "def main()" outside of all functions and classes, with no indentation. Then remove the "def main()", as it's not the main method you're thinking it is.

Comment: Why did you make `main` a method of `Solution`?

Answer (score 2):

Move your **main** function outside of the class, and then specifically execute it:

```
class Solution(object):
    def singleNumber(self, nums):

        for i in range(0,len(nums),2):
            if (i != len(nums) - 1) and (nums[i] != nums[i+1]):
                print (nums[i])
            elif i == len(nums) - 1:
                print (nums[i])

def main():
    nums=[1,1,2,2,3]
    s=Solution()
    s.singleNumber(nums)
    print('done')

main()
```

Output:

```
3
done
```

Another possibility is to make it a separate function at all: drop the **def main** line, un-indent the four lines of that code, and run it from the top level.

Comment: I'm not sure dropping `def main` is objectively better.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike many other programming languages, such as Java, Python does not require the `main` method to be inside a class. Even more, Python **does not need to have a `main` method defined**: it runs the whole file as an application. In your original post, Python performs this actions:

- Define the method `singleNumber` as the code it holds.
- Define the method `main` as the code it holds.
- Save this two methods inside the class `Solution`.
- No more lines to run, therefore ends application.

To make the application correct, you must write it as follows:

```
class Solution(object):
    def singleNumber(self, nums):
        for i in range(0,len(nums),2):
            if (i != len(nums) - 1) and (nums[i] != nums[i+1]):
                print (nums[i])
            elif i == len(nums) - 1:
                print (nums[i])

if __name__=='__main__':
    nums=[1,1,2,2,3]
    s=Solution()
    s.singleNumber(nums)
    print('done')
```

You may wonder why the line `if __name__=='__main__':`; every file contains the variable `__name__` implicitly defined and its value depends if you're running the file directly or it is imported. On the first case, the assignment `__name__='__main__'` is done, on the second case the `__name__` variable is assigned the name of the file itself; this gives you an idea whether this file is the main or not.

You may also discard the `Solution` class and promote the `singleNumber` method to a module method.